# Regex Replace anything but numbers and lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an input which I am binding to keyup()

On each keyup, I want it to:

1. disallow any characters that are not a number, a letter, or a dash, and
2. replace any uppercase characters with lowercase ones.

Regex makes my head explode, any help?

```
$('.my-input').keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-z-]/g,/[0-9a-z-]/g);
});
```

Comment: You've already got help with the RegEx part of this, but don't forget that users can enter data in your input without triggering the keyup event if they do it with the mouse (right-click and paste, drag'n'drop).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
this.value = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z-]/g,"");
```

Comment: this does not work as it does not allow for A-Z uppercase letters.. need to allow for them them downcase the ending result.... edit im dumb.. i see your toLower first :)

Comment: @ Jake - Since I convert to lower case before the replace, I do not need to look for upper case in the regex.

Comment: yeah i noticed the toLower after my comment.. made an edit to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.my-input').keyup(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z-]/g, '').toLowerCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex for a number, letter or dash is: `[-0-9a-z]` (to include a literal dash in your character class, specify it as the first character; thereafter it's considered a range operator).

Try:

```
$('.my-input').keyup(function() {this.value = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^-0-9a-z]/g,''); });
```

Comment: I just checked and javascript is less fussy than java - you can have the literal dash at the start or the end of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Good question.. you're almost there!

```
$('.my-input').keyup(function() { this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/g,"").toLowerCase();
```

Regex is not the right tool for lowercasing, use the built-in function. Your regex was good, but the replace function takes one regex and the replacement is a string, not a regex*.

(*replacement strings have some minor magic, but not enough for lowercasing)