# Regex replace anything but numbers with increments letter using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an equation/formula stored in database and I want it to be triggered based on key up input event in a webpage.

Example formula: `[55-57]`

This is a simple minus operation, where the number actually represents the id of a row in database

I have looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147433/regex-replace-anything-but-numbers-and-lowercase) which replaces numbers found in a string to `new value`. But I need the `new value` to be replaced with incremented letters such as `a`, `b` and so on. Also the leading and ending brackets `[]` need to be removed so that I can perform an `eval` later using JavaScript.

Later the equation will be convert to `a-b`. Variable `a` and `b` represent other HTML elements that holds a value. So whenever I key in something into text field, changes will reflect on other part of webpage. It's like auto computation.

Thank you for those helping this. Hope this question will help somebody.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, or give examples.  It is very confusing as is.

Comment: what don't you understand? I have change it a bit

Comment: So what should `[55-57]` become after replacement?

Comment: `a-b`. 55 and 57 are reference to other html element input (eg: `type="hidden"`)

Comment: So you want `<value of #55> - <value of #57>` ???  Yeah, that's ___not the slightest bit clear___ in your question.  What do you mean by "incremented letters"?  The same thing, e.g. `#a`?

Comment: I think what OP means is that he needs to keep track of variable names starting from 'a' and progressively increasing with a lexicographic logic.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul you should really try to organize a bit what you want to do so that you can extract the important part of the problem for us to help you with.

Comment: Very unclear question.  The question needs to show very specific strings that need to be evaluated.  Show us exactly what the input is and the desired output.

Comment: I try harder to organize the question above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.  If you need more help, you seriously need to re-word your question or post a jsfiddle, or something.

```
var eqn = '55-57'; // brackets removed.  Remove them with a regex of /\[|\]/g if you need to

var result = eval( eqn.replace( /\w+/g, function( res ){
    return +document.getElementById( res[1] );
} );
```

Basically this replaces `55` and `57` with the numerical values of `#55` and `#57`.  It would also work for `#b`, etc.

It then `eval`'s the result, basically doing whatever math is in your equation.